# Is it possible to make server push without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, server-push

Is there some mechanism to provide server push technology using plain HTML, without using javascript (or any other script languages on the client side).

Under "server push" I mean process where the server to update some part of the page content when needed.

Comment: Server push what?  An update to a part of a page?  A whole page?  New content at the end of the page?

Comment: @jfriend00: Updating some data on the page. Updating the whole page could be a solution too, but I am afraid, most web browsers will make the page to flash, thus generating heavy flickering image.

Comment: Server push as in an AJAX call? An alternative to that without the use of JS?

Comment: @Galadre: Well, for me, using AJAX is not mandatory. I have implementations of server-push without using any XML, only plain JS and some server-side programming. Notice, I am not web developer and may miss some knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way that true server push can be used without any javascript in the page.

Without javascript, the only thing I'm aware of is a [meta refresh tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) that would tell the browser to refresh this page after some particular time interval.  This tag applies to a whole page only.  If you wanted only part of a page to be updated, you could use an iframe and have only the iframe be updated.  Of course, this is not server push, but a client-driven auto-update and it will be run on a predetermined interval, not just when there is actually new data.  For something smarter than this, you will need javascript.

The most efficient server-push would be to use javascript from the page to connect to your server over a websocket and then have the server just send data to the page via the websocket whenever it wants (true server-push).  The client's javascript can then respond to the receipt of that websocket data by updating a particular piece of the page.